# Write a dataframe to csv file with value of NA as blank

Tags: r, csv, write.table

There is a `dataframe` named `cnbd`, for example:

```
cnbd = data.frame(1,2,3,NA,NA,5)
```

Thus the expression:

```
dim(cnbd)[1]
```

give 1.

I want to write a dataframe like `cnbd` to a csv with:

```
write(file = filename, cnbd, append = TRUE)
```

The problem comes:

1. The values of csv file show `cnbd` with 6 rows not 1 row as `1,2,3,NA,NA,5`.
2. I need output `cnbd` show as `1,2,3,,,5` in csv file, no NAs.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this:

```
write.table(df, "cnbd.csv",
            na = "",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            append = TRUE,
            sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 40):

You can try the write.csv command:

```
write.csv(cnbd, file="cnbd.csv", na="")
```

Comment: this kind of write mode will erase the former content,and add the row names and column name in the file,that's not my expected.could you give me details how to do?thanks very much