# How to Write a CSV in R where Blank Values are Null?

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export some data, however it contains blank values in some spaces. The data I imported (which is to be imported slightly modified, then exported) contains these blank, null values. After I export the file, these values are converted into blank strings. I want these values to stay as they were when I imported them.

They don't appear any different from a blank string in Excel, but when viewed in Notepad, the blanks appear as ,"", versus ,, as they do before being imported.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968717/write-a-dataframe-to-csv-file-with-value-of-na-as-blank) appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, however, it doesn't produce the desired (or described) result.

I've tried using `na = ""` and `na = NULL` in both `write.csv()` and `write.table()`. Is there a way of accomplishing this? I'll include a few examples below of what I've tried, they all produce either NAs or ""s where I'd like empty values in my CSV.

(It's worth noting, I've included both `NA`s and `""`s in this df, but I could easily standardize these values, so long as I can convert one to empty/null values in the CSV.)

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,NA,3,4), c(1,2,"",4))

write.table(df, "TestData.csv",
            na = "",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            append = FALSE,
            sep = ",")    
write.csv(df, "TestData.csv", na = character(0))
write.csv(df, "TestData.csv", na = "")
write.csv(df, "TestData.csv", na = NULL)
```

Comment: Your `write.table` option produced for me a file like you describe, with the NA replaced with <nothing> and the "" carried through: first col = 1, , 3, 4   second col = "1", "2", "", "4"

Comment: Not sure what was wrong before, but I reviewed that solution and you're right, it works fine! Thanks for pointing out my ignorance. Much appreciated!